# Column Chart Builder is not applying option useFirstColumnAsDomain

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization

I am trying to use column names as my x axis labels in a column chart using

```
.setOption("useFirstColumnAsDomain", true)
```

however it instead puts increments of .3 for the labels

I have tried just setting the ticks using

```
     .setOption("hAxis", { gridlines: { count: 5 }, ticks: ["Embed", "Initiate", "Practice", "Mature", "Hub & Extend"] })
```

to no avail

Here is the code I'm using to generate the data and chart

```
var data = Charts.newDataTable()
         .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "blank")
         .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "cat1")
         .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "cat2")
         .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "cat3")
         .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "cat4")
         .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "cat5")
 .addRow([1,parseInt(m[0]),parseInt(m[1]),parseInt(m[2]),parseInt(m[3]),parseInt(m[4])])
         .build();

     var xtextStyle = Charts.newTextStyle().setColor('black').setFontSize(12).build();
     var chart = Charts.newColumnChart()
      .setDimensions(1500, 1000)
      //.useLogScale()
      .setTitle(m[5] + "'s Dynamic Adventure Chart")
      .setOption('colors', ["#6c564d", "#db5d52", "#3f4b5d", "#56be93", "#dce24b"])
      .setDataTable(data)
      .setRange(0,5)
     .setOption("bar", {"groupWidth": '45%'})
     .setOption("vAxis", { ticks: [0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5]})
     .setOption("useFirstColumnAsDomain", true)
     .setOption('chartArea', {'width': '80%', 'height': '80%'})
      .build();
```

I want the x axis to be labeled based off of the column names (eg: cat1) but the x axis right now get labeled by increments of .3 (.3,.6,.9, etc...)

Comment: I think I understand the problem now -- you want different colors for each bar, so you added all the values to one row, in different columns. now you would like to have a label under each bar. is this correct? will you please share a pic of the chart, before the change we made for ticks?

Comment: yup. that's exactly it :) here's the picture https://i.imgur.com/EMWlEwj.png

Comment: any ideas how I would do this @WhiteHat?

Comment: don't think it's possible using apps script